# "npm install" independent of npmjs.org

Tags: node.js, npm

**npm install** downloads packages from npmjs.org, compiles and then installs. So even if the **node_modules** folder is taken backup it can not be used on other machines where the **os** might be different, due to the native machine code generated during the **npm install**.

Also another problem with **npm install** is that it downloads from npmjs.org. What if the site goes down?. How to download the packages and the same package be installed offline on all platforms?

Answer (score 2):

If you do keep the `node_modules` directory with your code, you can simply run [`npm rebuild`](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-rebuild.html) to re-compile anything that needs it.

Otherwise, you have a lot of options for installing from various locations.  You could keep package tarballs locally.  From [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-install.html):

```
npm install (with no args in a package dir)
npm install <tarball file>
npm install <tarball url>
npm install <folder>
npm install [@<scope>/]<name> [--save|--save-dev|--save-optional] [--save-exact]
npm install [@<scope>/]<name>@<tag>
npm install [@<scope>/]<name>@<version>
npm install [@<scope>/]<name>@<version range>
npm i (with any of the previous argument usage)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can tell npm to use a mirror if npmjs.org is down. For example:

```sh
npm set registry http://registry.npmjs.eu/
```

Or with a runtime option:

```sh
npm --registry http://registry.npmjs.eu/ install express
```